# Springframework PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java

Have question on PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. If properties file is changed, will spring loads it dynamically or do we have to start app for the changes to take effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're loaded on startup.

But [making them reloadable is completely doable](http://www.wuenschenswert.net/wunschdenken/archives/127).

Answer (score 2):

The properties are resolved and injected into your beans (only) during application startup. The PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer does not monitor and reload the configuration file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  Is there a way to monitor and reload the configuration file?