# How to reload Spring 4 context when property file changed

Tags: java, spring

How is it possible to reload Spring4 context when property file changed ?

Actually I use `@Value("$param{myParam}")` and I get the placeholder from my applicationContext.xml like this :

```
<bean id="param-PropertyPlaceholder"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="file:${confdir}/parameters.properties" p:placeholder-prefix="$param{" />
```

How can I the @Value changes when my property file changed ? Actually I must restart my application to be able to see changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599449/springframework-propertyplaceholderconfigurer

Comment: I don't want to set a timer to do that. There is no way to do that with native Spring classes ?

Comment: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer gets loaded only on application startup.

Answer (score 0):

I will create a method for that propose and decide when it will execute...

```
@Autowired
private MyBean1 myBean1

@Autowired
private MyBean2 myBean2

public void loadNewProperties() {
    // Read new properties into newProps
    ...
    // Load the new properties into bean fields
    myBean1.setPropertyA( newPropsp.getProperty( "property.A" ) );
    myBean2.setPropertyB( newPropsp.getProperty( "property.B" ) );
    ...
}
```

I think the properties are used when the system starts for the first time and during all the execution. I don't think your approach would be impossible but It will be complex.

If the properties are changing constantly you must consider use some datasource instead.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want that. Many applications rely on the singleton beans of an application context being the same through the whole application lifetime. But any bean can be asked to reload some values, or you can proxy some properties of singleton beans to protocol ones that will be rebuilt from scratch on each call.

I think that you have a perfectly acceptable design problem, but the solution is **not** the reload on demand of values extracted from a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Use frameworks for what they are good at, and do not try to make them do things that their developpers did not imagine.